# Datagrid With Button Column. How to bind the button's IsEnabled property to value of another column?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding myColumnName}" Header="Should Button In Second Column Be Enabled" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button>
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=myColumnName}" Value="No">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                                DoStuff
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

For each row I want the button to be disabled if Column1 contains "No" and enabled if it contains anything else.

Above is my broken attempt at the XAML - intellisense is telling me the

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled"
```

is not resolving properly.

What am I doing wrong here and what should I be doing instead to get my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Xaml to this way.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding myColumnName}" Header="Should Button In Second Column Be Enabled" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button>
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding myColumnName}" Value="No">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
Seems like I went off track. After further experimentation I realized that my troubles were due to me thinking I could style the button inside the DataTemplate the same way as I styled it on the form.

Trying to use your sample code still brought up the same compiler complaints as I listed in the question. It was complaining about Content being set more than once and Setter not being a valid property for Style.

However once I created DataTemplate.Resources tag and moved the style with TargetType button inside it, it was able to parse it properly.